# Can't start Ubuntu from USB flash drive

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I'm trying to test ubuntu on this old laptop I happen to have but I can't get past the boot menu. I choose the option to test ubuntu and when I press enter it freezes. There's no error messages or anything, I just get stuck on the boot selection screen. I've tried both 64 bit and 32 bit ubuntu and 2 different types of flash drives (USB 3.0 and 2.0). Is this just a problem with the computer? I know that in Window XP, It gets stuck on "Validating Identity" and never connects to wifi. Everything else works fine. It's a Gateway laptop - 4028GZ.

Comment: this may do the same thing but ... I was trying to get to a menu instead of the graphical "try Ubuntu" screen on a VM and click the x to close that screen and it went into the Ubuntu desktop as if I clicked the "try Ubuntu" option. So maybe try that  .. when you get to the screen that shows Try Ubuntu .. just close the window by clicking the X and say yes to canceling the install ... it may lock again .. or you may get into the desktop

Comment: You could perhaps try making the installation USB drive with a different USB creator. There are [many to choose from](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-live-usb-linux/): Rufus, LiLi, YUMI, UUI, UNetbootin, etc

Comment: @JohnOrion Nothing happens when I try that.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. The laptop CPU (Celeron M360 @1.4GHz with a 400MHz bus speed) does not support PAE, some sort of memory management in the CPU. The only solution is to install a version of Ubuntu older than 12.04 or another distro.

Comment: good catch .. didn't even think of that